# HBase schema Design

Tags: hbase

We have designed below Hbase schema which is kind of RDBMS style but the business requirements are forcing us to do so .

Lets say we have student entity and subjects entity there is one to many mapping between student and subjects

Students entity has below attributes

Name,
School,
Address,
country

Subjects has below attributes

SubjectName,
YearStudied, 
Subjectdescription,
passed/Failed,
Score

First design we nested subjects inside student entity where the student information was repeating for each subject .

something like rk subjectid, CF:Student(with student columns), CF:Subject(Subject columns

with this approach any updates to student attributes were a problem as they had to be applied across all the rows identifying them will be issue.

so we created two separate tables student and subjects and one of the column in students will hold all the row keys of subject table for that student.

I want to know what are the performance implications with such design.

Can anyone suggest better design options - we will have to do both read and writes to both students and subjects and have to use HBase !

Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema design seems faulty correct me if I am wrong?

How are you going to identify which subject to modify in case of and update in student table.

Suppose:

StudKey1:CF1:StdName,CF1:Coln,CF2:SubjectIds,CF2.Coln

Now if you need to modify details of any particular subject id say Sub_123 for StudKey1 how are you going to identify which subject to modify.
Unless you have a composite key in Subject table like ***StudKey_SubKey***. Now what if you need to add one more subject to course?

Now there are several solution which may defer to your use case.
You can try something like:

**Have 3 tables**

1. Student Table
2. Subject Table
3. Student_Subject_Match table

**Having keys as:**

1. Tbale1_Key:StudKey
2. Table2_key:SubKey
3. Table3_key:StudKey_SubKey OR StudKeySubKey (any way you can do fuzzy filtering or regex filtering)

This way you will be able to preserve all information about Student as well as Subject. If you need to modify any Subject information about a Student+Subject pair you can do so easily by firing an update on that student id subject id combination

Comment: We have that part of the key - subjects table row key has student table key prefixed .  Apart from the design the question is if Hbase is able to handle such design - what are the performance implications.

Comment: As for the question Can HBase handle such design YES it can.
Basically it can handle any design of RowKey Columns because they are byte arrays internally kept as key value pair.
Now for performance depends upon are you going to do scans on your table?
If yes then Until you use CoProcessors scan are going to be slow.
If no then no matter what your design is no matter how much data you have in your table Get and Put methods are going to give a constant performance

Comment: Can you explain how CoProcessors can be used to avoid scan ?

Comment: Coprocessors do not avoid scans they are a way to do scans.
Coprocessors parallelize the scans of HBase in such a way that the scan and aggregation of data occurs at the data node instead at client.
Then each individual node returns its subset of data to client which is then again combined and aggregated once more to output final result.
Search for EndPoint Coprocessors which are used to do so.

Comment: scans happen on each node unless you specify starkey and endkey where it will hit a particular node-region where the key is found so max it will scan one or two nodes (or more if your key ranges are spread across) ..... all other scans (using filters ) are full table scans unitl it hits the key so it can hit all nodes .... how does coprocessor help here is what I am trying to understand . I need to consider response time for prefix scan.